# WPF Call converter if collection item's property changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, converters

**PropertyChanged.Fody** is used. I have an ObservableCollection filled with custom class items. Each of them has a property IsTableSelected.

I want a button to be enabled if at least one of the items in the collection has property IsTableSelected set to true. The problem is: my Converter takes the collection as a value and doesn't get called if items in the collection change their properties.

Here is my XAML:

```
<Button 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    Content="Connect" 
    Margin="5"  
    IsEnabled="{Binding Tables, Converter={StaticResource selectedItemsToBoolConverter}}"
    />
```

Here is the item class:

```
public class ListBoxItemModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, e) => { };

    public bool IsTableSelected
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Here is the converter:

```
class SelectedItemsToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ObservableCollection<ListBoxItemModel> collection = value as ObservableCollection<ListBoxItemModel>;
        if (collection.Count > 0)
        {
            if (collection.Where(item => item.IsTableSelected == true).ToList().Count > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }

            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And just in case a line from the ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<ListBoxItemModel> Tables { get; set; } 
    = new ObservableCollection<ListBoxItemModel>();
```

Any way using MVVM would help.

Comment: Handle the collection's CollectionChanged event. When an item is added to the collection, handle the item's PropertyChanged event. In that handler, update a public boolean property: `IsAnyTableSelected = Tables.Any(x => x.IsTableSelected);`. Then bind IsEnabled to IsAnyTableSelected. BTW, compare my `Any()` expression to your `Where()` in the converter.

Comment: Thank you! It's a pity that CollectionChanged isn't called if I do Tables = tempCollection

Comment: It'd be fairly strange if it were. Two standard approaches to that: One: Give `Tables` a setter that removes all collection-changed/property-changed event handlers from the outgoing collection and its contents, and adds handlers to the incoming collection and all its contents. Two: Make `Tables` readonly, and to "replace" it, clear it and add the new items in a loop.